# In .Net 8 Blazor app how to inject services on the client only, and exclude from prerendering?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

On the server project, I have Account related pages (Register, Login) that are pre-rendered.
On the client project within _Imports.razor file I injected several services:

```cs
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    @inject ILocalStorageService LocalStorage
    @inject HttpClient HttpClient
    @inject IStringLocalizer<AppLanguage> Localizer
```

All client-side pages are not pre-rendered.
App.razor on the server:

```cs
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderModeForPage" />
    
    @code {
        [CascadingParameter]
        private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
    
        private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
            ? null
            : new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false);
    }
```

Now, when the app navigates to "/Account/AnyPage" the app throws an error saying that above injected services are not registered. I assume that during pre-rendering the server tries to access those services. However non of the server-side pages use client side services. If I remove those services from _Imports.razor everything works fine on the pre-rendered pages

How to exclude client-side injected services from pre-rendering?

Comment: On mobile so can't check details but a conditional compilation along the lines of #if net8.0-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Abstraction.

As an example, for the HttpClient move the API methods to a service with an interface and two implementations.

```cs
public class IWeatherForecastService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetWestherForecastsAsync(listRequest request);
}
```

You then have two implementations:

```cs
public class ClientWeatherForecastService : IWeatherForecastService
{
    private readonly IIHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public ClientWeatherForecastService(IIHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory ;
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetWestherForecastsAsync(listRequest request)
    {
        //Get the context and call the api
    }
}
```

Registered in the Server Services Container:

`Services.AddScoped<IWeatherForecastService,ClientWeatherForecastService>();`.

```cs
public class ServerWeatherForecastService : IWeatherForecastService
{
    public ClientWeatherForecastService(IIHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {}

    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetWestherForecastsAsync(listRequest request)
    {
        //go to the database and return a result - or maybe it's a stub and just returns an empty dataset?
    }
}
```

Registered in the Server Services Container:

`Services.AddScoped<IWeatherForecastService,ServerWeatherForecastService>();`.

You can now inject `IWeatherForecastService` into the component with no dependency on `HttpClient`.

Note you should be using `IIHttpClientFactory` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: There is one issue with that approach - server-side service returns the data without checking the authorization state. On a regular API call, I can use HttpContext, and the parameters read from cookies and HTTP headers within a controller.

Comment: For now, I disabled pre-rendering for all pages, except for those starting with "Account". On app start, I show an HTML and CSS spinner, until the app is loaded in the browser. For Account pages, I created a separate Layout. For me it feels dirty, but until I find a proper solution it should work.

Comment: Return an empty data set from the server side service.

Comment: Although the solution proposed by @mrc-aka-shaun-curtis worked for me, at the end I switched to the two separate projects: Blazor Webassembly Standalone app, with ASP.NET Core API app. A new Blazor template in .Net 8 is confusing. Even though I do not need to pre-render elements that depend on client-side services, I still have to do that as the services injected directly on the page will throw an exception. Also, it's a bad design pattern. ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WASM template in .Net 7 gives more control over frontend and backend sides.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You also need register this dependency inserver side:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51432#issuecomment-1766447888